# Why Firebase DB is jumping one level deeper?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the situation is following, I'm using Firebase DB for a small application, the structure of DB is the following.

[image: DB structure]

I'm aware this kind of structuring is not the best for Firebase, probably the problem is here.

My question is, when I'm trying to get childrens list from a parent, Firebase provides me with childrens list from one level deeper entity. For ex. related to this DB sample - if I try to get childrens list from the "University" entity, I get the output "Faculty", but should get the output "UNN". Am I right?

Here is the code sample I'm using for retreiving data:

```
 mDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("University");


        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_main);


        mGruppeChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(); // Result will be holded Here
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    lst.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey())); //add result into array list
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is because of firebase's onChildAdded method come with parameter of children of the parent you are reading from. If you added child event listener on 'University', you will get value like 'UNN'-->Faculty. Again if you perform getChildren method on this, you will get 'Faculty'-->RGF. So here if you apply getKey, off course it will return Faculty.

Comment: Brijesh, I appreciate your answer, finally I got it! But in this case "for each" loop is not applicable, right? Should I use a simple loop?

Comment: Well there is no requirement of loop. Just call getKey from dataSnapshot.

Comment: Well, you're right here, but I wanted to use a loop a bit deeper, where I have 5-6 children for each parent.

Comment: If you mean 'University' will have 5-6 children, in that case onChildAdded will automatically be called for 5-6 time depending on the number of children . you don't need to get children with loop. More if u wanna use loop, you can use valueEventListener in place of childEventListener.